# Naming params of nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

```
resources :leagues do
  resources :schedule
end
```

This generates:

```
leagues/:id
leagues/:league_id/schedule/:id
```

How can I keep the league ID from changing param names?
So it'll be:

```
leagues/:id
leagues/:id/schedule/:schedule_id
```

Answer (score 9):

No, please do not do this.

The reason for it being this way is that it provides a common interface for nested resources across every single application. By making it different in your application, you're effectively going "against the grain" of Rails. Rails has a strict set of conventions that you should stick to. When you stray from this path, things get messy.

---

However, if you do want to shoot yourself in the foot, metaphorically speaking, you will need to define the routes manually. Here's the routes for the seven standard actions in a controller:

```
get 'leagues/:id/schedules', :to => "schedules#index", :as => "league_schedules"
get 'leagues/:id/schedule/:schedule_id', :to => "schedules#show", :as => "league_schedule"
get 'leagues/:id/schedules/new', :to => "schedules#new", :as => "new_league_schedule"
post 'leagues/:id/schedules', :to => "schedules#create"
get 'leagues/:id/schedule/:schedule_id/edit', :to => "schedules#edit", :as => "ed it_league_schedule"
put 'leagues/:id/schedule/:schedule_id', :to => "schedules#update"
delete 'leagues/:id/schedule/:schedule_id', :to => "schedules#destroy"
```

As you can see, it's quite ugly. But, if you *really really really* want to do it this way, that's how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set "param" option on resource route to override the default "id" param:

```
resources :leagues do
  resources :schedule, param: schedule_id
end
```

refs to the Rails Routing Doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters

Comment: Tested this out with rails 4.2. This might have worked in the past but I can't seem to get it to work again.  Have you had luck getting this work on newer versions of rails?

Answer (score 0):

It appends the ID to the nested_param which is a bummer because I would like mine to be without the singular name. It looks like they really don't want you to make it only like `:id` as it could have conflicts. Plus it would be a bit of a diff from the normal restful routing that rails likes to use.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5368f2508651c92fbae40cd679afbafdd7e98e77/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1207

```
namespace :account, defaults: { type: 'account' }do
  resources :auth, param: :lies_id, only: [] do
    get :google
  end
end
```

Rake routes returns the following

```
$ rake routes | grep /account/auth
account_auth_google GET  /account/auth/:auth_lies_id/google(.:format)
```

So the solution which seams simpler is to just change the controller to use the nested param name it creates.