# Failing attempt to specify param name in nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider this route setup:

```
  resources :potatos do
    get "foo", to: "foo#foo"
  end
```

This generates a show route like this:

```
/potatos/:id
```

However the generated foo route is different:

```
/potatos/:potato_id/foo
```

I want the foo route to use the :id param, not :potato_id. This is because I have existing (shared) controller logic which expects an :id param

From the advice of [Naming params of nested routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666513/naming-params-of-nested-routes) I tried `resources(:potatos, param: :id)` but it had the same result.

Comment: Unrelated, but that's not the plural of "potato".

Comment: Why not pull the get route out of the nested resource like this `get '/potatos/:id/foo', to: 'foo#foo'` and `resources :potatos`

Comment: @user3366016 that's what I did as a workaround, but I'm fishing to see if there's another way

Comment: @maxpleaner makes sense.  I think this should work to keep it nested and a bit cleaner. I tend to pull this type of stuff out of the nested routes though.  `resources :potatos do
    get "foo", to: "foo#foo", on: :member
  end`

Comment: @user3366016 getting `undefined local variable or method 'on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper`. I might personally prefer to avoid nested routes as well, but I have to follow the dictum of my team.

Comment: I swear i tested it but with a slightly different format `resources :potatos do member do get "foo", to: "foo#foo" end end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just looking for various ways to achieve this. I thought I'd start an answer based on the comments to  show the various ways I've tried that work for me.

**The desired format is:**

`"/potatos/:id/foo" # :id refers to potato id`

**Outside of the resources block**

If you do not need a nested route in your routes.rb you can achieve This can be achieved by creating a custom route outside of the resources block.

```
# routes.rb
# Custom routes    
get '/potatos/:id/foo', to: 'foo#foo'
# Resources
resources :potatos
```

Rake routes shows:

```
GET potatos/:id/foo(.:format) foo#foo
```

I personally like this format as it allows me to see whats a typical resource and what I've added on. That said, I know the OP needs to follow a predefined style guide and ***needs it in the resources block*** (based on comment).

**Inside of the resources block**

If you need this done inside of the resources block, so far I've found adding a [member route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) to a different controller#action to work for me in a simple app.

```
  resources :potatos do
    member do
      get "foo", to: "foo#foo"
    end
  end
```

Or a simplified version if you only have one member.

```
  resources :potatos do
      get "foo", to: "foo#foo", on: :member
  end
```

both show the following when I rake routes:

```
foo_potatos GET /potatos/:id/foo(.:format) foo#foo
```

However, ***the OP recieves an error when trying this format***, but in my testing it works fine.

Comment: I didn't realize that `member` was some kind of special variable. I actually tried `on: :id` which didn't work. thanks, will try this today